# Black screen after login Kubuntu 17.10

Tags: kubuntu, 17.10, intel-graphics

When I boot my linux system (now Kubuntu 17.10), I get the normal login screen. I can login and briefly see my desktop (nothing is clickable), and a few seconds later I get a black screen with just the cursor. This happens every time I restart. I'm almost ready to give up and install RedHat, SuSE or a distro that is not based on Ubuntu with better video support!

I have an integrated Intel video chipset. Output from lspci:

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

PC is a 2nd Gen Intel Core i5

Things I have tried (all give the same exact result):

- Upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10
- Adding another user account and logging in
- Removing noveau and fglrx drivers
- Reinstalling intel drivers:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel    
  sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
  ```
- Booting using the live CD and repairing packages

  ```
  sudo dpkg --configure -a    
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade -y
  ```
- Booting with only one monitor connected

My system had been working just fine with 17.04 for the last year, not sure it was an update or a corruption.

- [EDIT] I also tried adding 'nomodeset' to /etc/default/grub by changing 
  this line:
      GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
  running update-grub.
  This resulted in a strange white screen and hanging on reboot, and on 
  2nd reboot, I got the same result as before (with the addition of a 
  superimposed ubuntu logo for a few seconds and only 1 monitor working)

Comment: So I was able to to get a GUI back by installing gnome (after reversing the 'nomodeset' change). It's not quite KDE, but I'll live with it...at least I don't have to completely reinstall everything.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
sudo reboot
```

Then install proprietary drivers